# Chrome TCP connection queuing for many seconds

Tags: javascript

In the Chrome developer tools, I notice that I have 6 TCP connections to a particular origin. The first 5 connections are idle from what I can tell. For the last of those connections, Chrome is making a call to our amazon S3 to get some images per the application logic. What I notice is that all the requests for that connection are queued till a certain point of time (say T1) and then the images are downloaded. Of course, this scenario is hard to reproduce, so I am looking for some hints on what might be going on.

My questions:

1. The connection in question does not have the "initial connection" in the timing information, which means that the connection might have been established before in a different tab. Is that plausible?
2. The other 5 connections for the same origin are to different remote addresses. Is that the reason they cannot be used to retrieve images that the 6th connection is retrieving?
3. Is there a mechanism to avoid this queueing delay in this scenario on the front end?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/understanding-resource-timing) (emphasis mine)

> A request being queued indicates that:
>
> - The request was postponed by the rendering engine because it's considered lower priority than critical resources (such as
>     scripts/styles). This often happens with images.
> - The request was put on hold to wait for an unavailable TCP socket that's about to free up.
> - **The request was put on hold because the browser only allows six TCP connections** per origin on HTTP 1. Time  spent making disk cache
>     entries (typically very quick.)

This could be related to the amount of images you are requesting from your amazon service. According to this excerpt, requests on different origins should not impact each other.

If you are loading a lot of images, then considering sprite sheets or something may help you along - but that will depend on the nature of the images you are requesting.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and I am requesting a lot of images. However, why does the first (and all subsequent) image request for that connection get queued for ~30 seconds is what does not make sense.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing else hitting the same origin higher in the page load? Cause that seems like the most likely culprit...

Comment: I have looked through the data, and there are no requests for that particular connection ID above the one I highlighted. I do not have data for the other Chrome tabs, so it is possible that there might be data exchange going on in another tab on the same connection. That sounds rather unlikely, but possible. Is there any other explanation?

Comment: Origin != Connection. Look for requests that hit the same domain.

Comment: I am not sure I am following. Per the docs, there can be a maximum of 6 connections per origin. I thought each connection worked independently to fetch the data as needed. Or are you saying that if a  connection is fetching data from the same domain, then it may impact the ability (on the client side) of another connection to fetch data from the same domain?

Comment: Each connection does work independently - but if there are too many connections then they join a queue. The [origin](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6454#section-7) is the page that initiated the request - not the destination. So the only real way you are likely to fix this problem is by either making less requests, or making them more strategically (using techniques such as lazy loading for example)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are making too many requests at once.

Since there is restriction on maximum number of active requests to 6 in HTTP 1.1 all other requests will get queued until the active requests get completed.

As alternative, you can use HTTP 2 / Speedy at Server which dosen't have any such restriction and many other benefits for applications making huge number of parallel requests.

You can easily enable HTTP 2 on nginx / apache.

Comment: As I mentioned, the very first request for that connection itself is queued up for 30s. I do not have data for the other Chrome tabs, so it is possible that there might be data exchange going on in another tab on the same connection. That sounds rather unlikely, but possible. Is there any other explanation?

Comment: Yes, there are many extension which stalls your request for ~5-10sec , for checksum calculations & other things like Websense Endpoints etc. Check if any such extension is installed in chrome.